# add list column to rowwise() dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of `dplyr::rowwise()`'d dataframes. Specifically whether I can apply `dplyr::mutate()` to them to create list columns that contain multiple objects.

In the example below I'm attempting to add a column to `mtcars` where each element/row is a list of length two, containing two `lm` models.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

## attempt to output two objects into a list
## -----> this does not work <-----
## why not?
mtcars %>%
  nest_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(mods = list(
    mymod1 = list(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = data)),
    mymod2 = list(lm(disp ~ wt, data = data))
  ))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `mods`.
#> x Input `mods` can't be recycled to size 1.
#> ℹ Input `mods` is `list(...)`.
#> ℹ Input `mods` must be size 1, not 2.
#> ℹ Did you mean: `mods = list(list(...))` ?
#> ℹ The error occurred in row 1.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

I can't quite make sense of the error message. Could anyone please help to clarify what's going on here?

Here are some related calls that *do* work, that led me to expect that the call above would also work.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

## output one object
## this works
mtcars %>%
  nest_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(mod = list(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = data)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Rowwise:  cyl
#>     cyl                data mod   
#>   <dbl> <list<tbl_df[,10]>> <list>
#> 1     4           [11 × 10] <lm>  
#> 2     6            [7 × 10] <lm>  
#> 3     8           [14 × 10] <lm>

## output one object into a list
## this also works
mtcars %>%
  nest_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(mod = list(
    mymod = list(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = data))
  ))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Rowwise:  cyl
#>     cyl                data mod         
#>   <dbl> <list<tbl_df[,10]>> <named list>
#> 1     4           [11 × 10] <list [1]>  
#> 2     6            [7 × 10] <list [1]>  
#> 3     8           [14 × 10] <list [1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

p.s. I understand that this can be achieved with other methods. This is mostly a learning opportunity :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store a list of length 1 in a dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1)
tmp <- list(mymod1 = lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars))
length(tmp)
#[1] 1

df$b <- tmp
```

But you cannot store a list of length more than 1.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1)
tmp <- list(mymod1 = lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars), 
            mymod2 = lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars))
length(tmp)
#[1] 2

df$b <- tmp
```

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, b, value = list(mymod1 = list(coefficients = c(`(Intercept)` = 37.285126167342,  :
> replacement has 2 rows, data has 1

For that again you need to make a list of length 1 which can be done as -

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1)
tmp <- list(list(mymod1 = lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars), 
                 mymod2 = lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)))
length(tmp)
#[1] 1
df$b <- tmp
```

---

So for your example this will work -

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  nest_by(cyl) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(mods = list(list(mymod1 = list(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = data)),
                          mymod2 = list(lm(disp ~ wt, data = data))))) 

#    cyl                data mods            
#  <dbl> <list<tibble[,10]>> <list>          
#1     4           [11 × 10] <named list [2]>
#2     6            [7 × 10] <named list [2]>
#3     8           [14 × 10] <named list [2]>
```

which is also what the error message suggests to do.

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah for such a clearly explained answer. Seems obvious now!